# How to make smooth slide down menu { Preferably by css3 or little JS lines with explanation }

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, slide

i need to make slide down menu without javascript/jquery or by little from them, i'm trying to avoid js because i'm beginner in that.

i've been play around with Css3 to make this thing done and after many fails i made it by animation but it still have some bugs when setting animation-delay property and there is the code :

```css
* {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav > ul {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center
}

nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative
}

nav > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #7f8c8d;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px
}


/* ANIMATE UL TO SLIDE DOWN WHEN HOVER */

nav > ul > li > ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: slideUp;
  animation-duration: 150ms;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
  animation-name: slideDown;
  visibility: visible;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  from {
    height: 0px
  }
  to {
    height: 200px
  }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    height: 200px
  }
  to {
    height: 1px
  }
}


/* END ANIMATION */

nav > ul > li > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 1px
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: #bdc3c7;
  color: #000
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu li</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="sub"><a href="#">sub</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub"><a href="#">sub</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub"><a href="#">sub</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub"><a href="#">sub</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu li</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">sub</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sub</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sub</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sub</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu li</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">sub</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sub</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sub</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sub</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu li</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu li</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

There is a [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPPRpR) without setting delay

and this's when setting animation-delay property [codepin](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVVeJq)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly is your bug/problem? what do you want to achieve? animation seems smooth already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it less buggy by simply removing some of your css. The advanced animation properties are unnecessary for such a task.

These are the properties I changed:

```
nav > ul > li > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 3s ease;
    height: 0;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    height: 200px;
}
```

And here's the [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKKXZO)

Comment: one more question and sorry for inconvenience, is there any way to set delay for slide out when mouseout ?

Comment: I just had a play around, I think I've achieved what you want using the `transition-delay` property. The trick was to set it to the desired delay on the `nav > ul > li > ul` selector and reset it to `0s` on hover. I've updated the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKKXZO) (same link), see what you think.

Comment: once again thank you very mush, you are the best man 1++ for you answer.